# React JS DateTimePicker issue - Changing the time 12:01pm and 1:59pm - updated into next date

Tags: reactjs

There is issue on DateTimePicker and DatePicker.

I am trying to modify the time as 12:10pm or 12:20pm in the DateTimePicker drop down, but it is changing the date as next day.

Example :- If the date is 12-Mar-2021, After modification in time drop down as 12:10PM, then the original date has changed to 13-Mar-2021.

It happens when only when i change the time as custom one, not happen with pre-defined drop down list example:- 12:30pm, 1:00pm.

I tried with all this solutions:-
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1018

Comment: Code-My code:-

 `<DateTimePicker
      className={styles.dates}
      value={from}
      onSelect={setFrom}
     />
    ) <DatePicker
      className={styles.dates}`enter code here`
      value={from}
      onSelect={date => setFrom(date)}
      utcOffset={0}
     />`

Comment: 1. Put your code into your question. 2. If you can reproduce your issue in a sandbox, it will make it much easier to troubleshoot.